# T-SQL Need assistance with creating indexes on sql_variant columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, indexing

I need some assistance for creating indexes on table. The table has the following structure:

```
RowsetID INT
Col001 SQL_VARIANT
Col002 SQL_VARIANT
....
Col255 SQL_VARIANT
```

The table store a lot of informations (milions of rows) in the following way:

```
RowsetID    Col001  Col002  Col003  Col004  ... Col255
1           1       Ivan    10      NULL        NULL
1           2       Petar   11      NULL        NULL
...
1           n       Petko   m       NULL        NULL
...
2           10      Germany 120     NULL        NULL
2           11      Japan   121     NULL        NULL
...
2           m       Poland  120     NULL        NULL
...
4           120     Europe          NULL        NULL
4           121     Asia            NULL        NULL
```

Please, note that this is a sample data use only to describe the situation.
The idea is to store different information in separated rowsets.

Now, I need to get all this information like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT Col001,Col002,Col003
    FROM DataTable
    WHERE RowsetID=1
)AS RowsetOne
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Col001,Col002,Col003
    FROM DataTable
    WHERE RowsetID=2
)AS RowsetTwo ON RowsetOne.Col003=RowsetTwo.Col001
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Col001,Col002,Col003
    FROM DataTable
    WHERE RowsetID=4
)AS RowsetFour ON RowsetTwo.Col003=RowsetFour.Col001
...
```

In my real situations, I have many rowsets and columns that I need to join and they are millions of rows,so the view that contains the select above is slow.

I have decided to create indexes on the table like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PersonsPersionID] ON DataTable
(
    Col001
)
WHERE RowsetID=1

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PersonsCountryID] ON DataTable
(
    Col003
)
WHERE RowsetID=1

...

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CountriesCountryID] ON DataTable
(
    Col001
)
WHERE RowsetID=2
```

My idea was to create index on each column that I am using as join column, but at the final, no optimization was achieved.

Could you advice what type of index I should create? I have spent a lot of hours reading T-SQL Indexes [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) but it is more about what type of indexes you can create, not when to use them.

Comment: Why are you stuffing this junk into `SQL_VARIANT`? There are such better ways to solve this type of problem...

Comment: are you trying to recreate EAV but with complex types? It feels like what you need is a document data store, where you can define the fields for each column, so you at least have some mechanism of commonality.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's not my choice, and I am not allowed or able to rewrite the whole company logic. Sometimes, you are in such situations and you have to work with what you got.

Comment: @jcolebrand Could you tell in more details what is your idea?

Comment: A document data store is not a traditional RDBMS like SQL or Oracle, but rather something like Couch or Mongo. A completely different technology. It just seems like you're trying to recreate a document model, which is not an RDBMS strength.